What is the right interpretation of Lk 10:18 with cross reference to Mtt 17:19-21?
We read how Jesus reprimands his disciples who were not able to heal an epileptic boy, attributing it to their lack of faith,  in Mtt 17:19-21.
But, in Lk 10:17-20 Jesus gives a seemingly moderate  compliment to the disciples:

Then the seventy returned with joy, saying, “Lord, even the demons are subject to us in Your name.” And He said to them, “I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven. .....'

Presumably, the incident in Luke happened after that in Matthew , after the disciples had grown in faith. But, some scholars interpret the Verse of Jesus referring to Satan's fall as an outcome of pride thereby cautioning the disciples against too much of pride in their faith. Some others say that the Verse refers to Jesus' recap on casting away of demons by the disciples, weakening the hold of the devil .  My question is : What is the right interpretation of Lk 10:18 in as much as it refers to lightning-like fall of Satan from heaven ?
PS: Questions on Lk 10:18 are already available on BHE. I am soliciting scholars' views with particular reference to Mtt 17:19-21. Please bear with me.

Unscoped questions still belong on Hermeneutics. You should know this by now.

Which 'scholar's' are you requesting views from ? One could find a whole spectrum of 'scholastic' opinion on the subject.

I would assume that the scholars requested would be "any" and that might have mentioned both things together. I don't believe Kadalikatt knows which scholar he wants, thus cannot provide that detail

Well, Wyrsa. Now that you have come with an answer, you are as good as a scholar to me !

Assuming Markan priority, both Luke and Matthew borrow from Mark here (Mark 9:14-29). Scholars have often noted that Mark takes a rather dim view of the apostles. They consistently fail to understand Jesus, harden their hearts toward him, and misinterpret his mission. According to the late Hugh Anderson of the University of Edinburgh:

Mark's dominant theme is the disciples' lack of understanding in the
face of the truth. They misunderstand that God's way of suffering and
sacrifice for Jesus is identical with God's way for His disciples.

Luke, on the other hand, wants to show that the Holy Spirit worked through the apostles, especially in the early church (in the Book of Acts) but also during Jesus' earthly ministry. He thus portrays them as understanding Jesus better that they do in Matthew and especially in Mark. Thus, according to the editors of the NABRE:

The effect of the mission of the seventy-two is characterized by the
Lucan Jesus as a symbolic fall of Satan. As the kingdom of God is
gradually being established, evil in all its forms is being defeated;
the dominion of Satan over humanity is at an end.

Matthew's version, like Mark's, criticizes the apostles for the lack of faith but omits the fact that the boy's father, apparently unlike the apostles themselves, did have faith. (Mk 9:23-24) Luke alone does not mention the apostles' faithlessness but emphasizes Jesus' rejoicing that the Father has so empowered them.
Conclusion: Luke and Matthew both come on the foundation of Mark, who rather consistently portrayed the apostles in a bad light.  Luke "corrects" this more radically than Matthew does, showing them to cooperate and understand Jesus as his comrades in the battle against Satan.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman. If would be nice if you add a line or or two on why Jesus mentioned the fall of Satan while appreciating the work of the disciples .

@KadalikattJosephSibichan I think it foreshadows or prophesies  that the apostles would be instrumental in spreading God's dominion through their witnessing to the Gospel. Jesus could not do this without the response of the disciples.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman.

Well... the first thing I noticed is that the event of the "requires prayer and fasting" is recorded in both Matthew and Luke.


Matthew goes on in the following terms: “And when He was come to the multitude, there came to Him a certain man, kneeling down before Him, and saying, Lord, have mercy on my son; for he is lunatic, and sore vexed;” and so on, down to the words, “Howbeit this kind is not cast out but by prayer and fasting.”[Matthew 17:14-20] Both Mark and Luke record this incident, and that, too, in the same order, without any suspicion of a want of harmony. (Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers, Series 1, Volume 6, page 155) (St. Augustine, Sermon on the Mount, Harmony of the Gospels)



... tell you indeed, to learn those things which I have granted to some, to whom I would, not to all, to raise the dead, to give sight to the blind, to open the ears of the deaf; nor to wish as for some great thing to learn these things of Me.” The disciples returned with joy and exultation, saying, “Lo, even the devils are subject unto us through Thy Name.” [Luke 10:17] And the Lord said to them, “In this rejoice not, that the devils are subject unto you; rejoice rather, because your names are written in heaven.”[Luke 10:20] To whom He would, He gave the power to cast out devils, to whom He would, He gave the power to raise the dead. Such miracles were done even before the Incarnation of the Lord; the dead were raised, lepers were cleansed; we read of these things. And ... (Ibid, page 534, St. Augustine, same sermons)

So you definitely have the concern of pride in those verses. However this is the same set of "sermons" from St. Augustine, and both of the passages you requested are mentioned.
Perhaps investigate "Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers, Series 1, Volume 6" and the sermons of St. Augustine?

Regarding "fall of satan"
I've found much commentary in connection with "Get thee behind Me, Satan" and how Jesus gave the power against him...


Also the power which He said He received after the resurrection, that He had before He received it, and before the resurrection. For He of Himself rebuked Satan, saying, ‘Get thee behind Me, Satan;’ and to the disciples He gave the power against him, when on their return He said, ‘I beheld Satan, as lightning, fall from heaven[Luke 10:18-19].’ And again, that what He said that He had received, that He possessed before receiving it, appears from His driving away the demons, and from His unbinding what Satan had bound, as He did in the case of the daughter of Abraham; and from His remitting sins, saying to the paralytic, and to the woman who washed His feet, ‘Thy sins be ... (Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers, Series 2, Volume 4, page 415, St Athanasius/Against the Arians)



... you see brothers at strife you laugh; and are glad that some are called by your name and others by that of Christ. Better would it be to imitate Jonah and say: “If it is for my sake that this great tempest is upon you, take me up and cast me forth into the sea.” He in his humility was thrown into the deep that he might rise again in glory to be a type of the Lord. But you are lifted up in your pride to the stars, only that of you too Jesus may say: “I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven.”[Luke 10:18] (Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers, Series 2, Volume 6, page 280, The letters of St. Jerome)

Pride does seem to be a central theme here... there is other directions you can go and use the verse for. As you have pointed out, but pride is definitely valid exegesis here assuming you considered the homilies of the church fathers to be valid.
